Getting error of invalid href value for my link preloader
I have this image on my HTML file , but getting below error <link rel=preload> has an invalid href value
  <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" href={{mainImageUrl1024()}} as="image" media="(min-width:1024px)" />
  <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" href={{mainImageUrl768()}} as="image" media="(min-width:768px)" />
  <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" href={{mainImageUrl()}} as="image" />

and how I load this href values :
mainImageUrl(): string {
   return this.baseUrl + '?w=450&h=200&fit=crop&auto=format';
}


Maybe this warning is a bug
[as]- this attribute is used when rel="preload" or rel="prefetch" has been set on the element. It specifies the type of content being loaded/prefetched Instead, 'preload' you can also use 'prefetch'
<link rel="prefetch" >

So we can accomplish the task
